# Where is config file for QGIS 2.18?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, configuration

I search the config (.ini) file for QGIS 2.18 on my pc.
For QGIS 3.4.8 the file is stored under this path
C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\QGIS\QGIS3

I can´t find this file for QGIS 2.18.

Where is this file normaly stored?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [QGIS Documentation for 2.18](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#advanced-settings), for a Windows OS it is stored in your registry.

So, in your windows start menu, type `regedit` to open your registry. There, you can find it under: `HKEY\CURRENT_USER\Software\QGIS\QGIS2`

I run 2.18 as well and I can see it in my registry. Depending on your OS version, it can differ slightly (such as `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` instead of `HKEY\CURRENT_USER`).

Comment: Ok, but where can I find the .ini file ? For QGIS 3.4.8 the config file is a .ini which I can open in a text editor and can change for example the standard crs for example. This file I need for QGIS 2.18

Comment: I'm not sure if there even is a .ini file to begin with. I think that the registry file is located in your QGIS installation folder, most likely something like this: `C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis\bin\qgis.reg`.